# Cant boot UEFI multi-boot USB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, uefi, arch-linux

Today I tried making an UEFI multiboot flash drive. What I did:

1. Created 4 partitions (Refind + Arch + ElemantaryOS + Ubuntu)
2. Formatted all with FAT32
3. Copied refind to the first partition.
4. Copied contents of Arch ISO to the second partition.
5. Copied contents of ElemantaryOS ISO to the third one.
6. Copied contents of Ubuntu ISO to the fourth one

The problem is that Ubuntu is the only one that boots. Tried it on another system and it just worked. What could be different between the computers?